# AWS Lambda publish message to SNS From VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-iam, amazon-sns

I am trying to send a message from a lambda function to a sns topic. My Lambda execution role has all the SNSFullAccess to publish, I created an endpoint on my VPC to let the sns service interact with my lambda by specifying the private subnet associated with my lambda.

My lambda got the full memory it can get (3008MB) and a timeout of 45 seconds.

I use boto3 here is the code used to publish the message :

```
client = boto3.client('sns')
publish_response = client.publish(
    TopicArn='<my-topic-arn>',
    Message="Hello"
)
```

My lambda function timeout and can't achieve to publish the message.

I don't know what to do anymore...

Comment: *"I created an endpoint on my VPC to let the sns service interact with my lambda"* - not sure what that means but it would be the wrong way around anyway. You would need to follow https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-vpc-create-endpoint.html or not have you lambda in a VPC.

Comment: Sorry for the miscomprehension, that means that I already followed these steps and now I have the amazon endpoint for sns services

Comment: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/lambda-reachability-analyzer might help

Comment: Security groups? Follow instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html). PS reduce your Lambda function timeout to 10 seconds while testing, if all you're doing is publishing to SNS - turnaround time will be quicker and debugging will be  cheaper.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I fixed my endpoint for sns service security group, now it let the lambda security group and the reachability analyzer is a success. But I still have a timeout when i execute my lambda...

Comment: Is the SNS topic in the same region as the VPC? The endpoint is usually regional, i.e. if you're sending messages from eu-central-1 to a us-east-1 topic, the VPC endpoint won't help.

Comment: Yes the sns is in the same region, moreover I have trigger on the topic that start lambda function and it works when I publish message on the amazon console.

Answer (score 0):

I set this up in my environment and was able to re-create your error and fix it appropriately.  Here are the key things you'll need to setup for it to function correctly:

1. Lambda setup with permissions to publish to SNS and permissions to attach to VPC.
2. Create a new security group for lambda access to SNS in the VPC.
   -- Add an outbound rule for all ports to 0.0.0.0/0.
   -- Add *INBOUND* rule for HTTPS from your VPC CIDR.
3. Attach the lambda to the VPC and add the new lambda security group.
4. Add an SNS VPC Endpoint and attach the new lambda security group.

You could alternatively create two security groups, but I'm not sure you gain any additional security in doing so.  The inbound rule is what fixed the issue and I was able to publish with a 3 second timeout in place.

Comment: Least privilege is a security best practice. Two security groups would be better: one on the VPC Endpoint and the other on the Lambda function(s), with the former allowing ingress from the latter.

Comment: I think in most cases you put the security group on the vpc endpoint and allow inbound HTTPS from the whole CIDR since you want the whole CIDR to use it.  Otherwise it's a lot of upkeep. But OP can lock it down once he has a working pattern.